# how i establish internet connection in Android Emulator in Mac OS?

Tags: android, titanium

I am using Titanium Studio. i have install android AVD and it work properly. and also have iphone simulator and also work properly. when i use inter browser in iphone than work properly. but not work or android emulator. how i establish connection in Android Emulator ? plz Help if any suggestion Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

normally the Android Virtual Device (AVD) already has a working internet connection.
Did you try to delete the AVD and create a new one?

Eclipse offers an Emulator Control panel in DDMS - if you've got the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) you could try to install the [Android Developer Tools (ADT)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and have a look if internet connection (Data in the Panel) got disabled.

When I used Titanium I didn't have any problems with the AVD btw.

Comment: how i do this? some explain.
how i delete AVD and new create..?

Comment: i see it have DDMS in SDK how i install ADT?

Comment: Follow this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html - for DDMS: Just use ./ddms in your SDK tools folder

Comment: let try step by step u tell me first i delete the avd and than create new avd. right